# sizeof(int) on x64?

Tags: c#, 64-bit, clr, sizeof

When I do `sizeof(int)` in my C#.NET project I get a return value of 4.  I set the project type to x64, so why does it say 4 instead of 8?  Is this because I'm running managed code?

Comment: Unmanaged code makes the same decision as .NET. In plain C++, sizeof(int) is 4 as well. Think of x64 as extensions to a 32-bit architecture. The default is still 32, you just gain the ability to process 64-bit data *as well*.

Comment: @jalf to be more precise, we already had the ability to process 64-bit data, however the x64 CPUs do it faster due to native support.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There are [various 64-bit data models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit); Microsoft uses [LP64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) for .NET: both *long*s and pointers are 64-bits (although C-style pointers can only be used in C# in `unsafe` contexts or as a  `IntPtr` value which cannot be used for pointer-arithmetic). Contrast this with ILP64 where *int*s are also 64-bits.

Thus, on all platforms, `int` is 32-bits and `long` is 64-bits; you can see this in the names of the underlying types [`System.Int32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32) and [`System.Int64`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int64).

Comment: You should edit your answer as it is the accepted one to make it completely correct. Remove where you say "although traditional C-style pointers don't exist .NET" and detail System.IntPtr depends on the architecture.

Comment: You can use "C-style" pointers in C#, they just have to be done under the unsafe context. Like "fnieto" said, you need to note that IntPtr does depend on the platform, where "sizeof(IntPtr)==4" in x86 & "sizeof(IntPtr)==8" in x64.

Answer (score 53):

The keyword `int` aliases `System.Int32` which still requires 4 bytes, even on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: What about alignment on a CPU word boundary? Even a single `Byte` _may_ be 64-bits wide on x64.

Answer (score 28):

[`int`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types) means `Int32` in .NET languages. This was done for compatibility between 32- and 64-bit architectures.

Here's the [table of all the types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/built-in-types) in C# and what they map to .NET wise.

Answer (score 19):

An `Int32` is 4 bytes on x86 and x64. An `Int64` is 8 bytes either case. The C# `int` type is just an alias for `System.Int32`. Same under both runtime environments. The only type that does change depending on the runtime environment is an `IntPtr`:

```
    unsafe
    {
        var size = sizeof(IntPtr); // 4 on x86 bit machines. 8 on x64
    }
```

Comment: Or you could just check IntPtr.Size, which does not require unsafe code.

Comment: Good thing to note: UIntPtr is not CLS-Compliant.

Answer (score 14):

You may be thinking of an `int` pointer or `System.IntPtr`.  This would be 8 bytes on an x64 and 4 bytes on an x86.  The size of a pointer shows that you have 64-bit addresses for your memory.  (`System.IntPtr.Size` == 8 on x64)

The meaning of `int` is still 4 bytes whether you are on an x86 or an x64.  That is to say that an `int` will always correspond to `System.Int32`.

Answer (score 6):

Remember `int` is just a compiler alias for the basic type `Int32`. Given that it should be obvious why `int` is only 32 bits on a 64 bit platform.

Answer (score 2):

```
int i;
int size = BitConverter.GetBytes(i).GetLength(0);
```

[Fiddle Sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lfH5GZ)

Comment: This question was asked 3 years ago and already has an accepted answer. See if you can provide answers to recent questions that do not yet have an accepted answer.