# long on a 64 bit machine

Tags: c#, .net, types

Is a long 128 bits on a 64 bit machine?

**Edit:** Duplicate question; see [sizeof(int) on x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651956/sizeofint-on-x64).

Comment: Duplicate question. Good answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651956/sizeofint-on-x64

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On both 32-bit and 64-bit machines:

- `long` is 64-bit, it's a synonym for `System.Int64`.
- `int` is 32-bit, it's a synonym for `System.Int32`.

Answer (score 1):

Nope ... 64 bits

Answer (score 1):

long.MinValue and long.MaxValue are your friend