# How to build the 32-bit GRPC binaries from sources with CMAKE on Linux (CentOS 7)?

Tags: linux, cmake, grpc

Does anyone know how to build the 32-bit GRPC binaries from sources with CMAKE on Linux (CentOS 7)? Which specific flags must be set to what specific values and passed to CMAKE in which specific way?

We know how to build the 64-bit GRPC binaries from sources with CMAKE on Linux but we also need its 32-bit version. I would imagine that there has to be a way to turn off the default 64-bit build and turn on the 32-bit build instead.

Thank you.

Comment: Hint https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51637965/cmake-create-and-link-32bit-and-64bit-versions-of-library .......... There are 32bit grpc rpm´s, but not for CentOS 7. ...... Hint-2 : grpc git version was built with the 32bit CentOS 7 - i686 OS. Compiler was g++-7.5, i.e. g++-4.8.5 failed.

Comment: GRPC 32bit binaries, EL7 → `grpc-git102421-bin-1.el7.tar.xz` (libstdc++.so.6.0.24 included) →  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KVeQmcFs_8x1bPYJbUk2Gr7NRGtmymcP/view?usp=sharing