# How to calculate size of Nullable<T> datatypes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

Actually, i am willing to know that how much memory is being consumed by following datatypes

**int? = memory size?**

**double? = memory size?**

**bool? = memory size?**

Can anybody give me information about their storage or a method to calculate their size

Comment: It has not been answered anywhere properly, There has to be an exact answer everybody just copy and paste the answer from different blogs. Event they don

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to know the memmory consumption of e.g. a `int? x`? MSDN says:

> ... The common language runtime assigns storage based on the
>   characteristics of the platform on which your application is
>   executing. In some circumstances it packs your declared elements as
>   closely together as possible; in other cases it aligns their memory
>   addresses to natural hardware boundaries. Also, storage assignment is
>   different on a 64-bit platform than it is on a 32-bit platform.
>
> The same considerations apply to each member of a composite data type
>   such as a structure or an array. Furthermore, some composite types
>   have additional memory requirements. For example, an array uses extra
>   memory for the array itself and also for each dimension. On a 32-bit
>   platform, this overhead is currently 12 bytes plus 8 bytes for each
>   dimension. On a 64-bit platform the requirement is doubled. You cannot
>   rely on simply adding together the nominal storage allocations of the
>   components.
>
> An Object referring to any elementary or composite data type uses 4
>   bytes in addition to the data contained in the data type.

Comment: Mithrandir can you please explain above in general way because all i want to know is that double?(nullable double) would occupy how much bytes on 32 bit machine and how much double?(nullable double) would occupy on 64-bit machine.

Comment: The actual size may change from system to system. You can use sizeof() to get the actual value at runtime, but then what?

Comment: Please try out if you can because i have tried but i couldn't i have tried out every stupid trick

Answer (score 2):

answer, I believe, is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381308/what-is-the-memory-footprint-of-a-nullablet)

Basically, add to the size of the non-nullable the size of a bool.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to get the actual size at runtime. The value returned will be the same as the element alignment of an array `int?[]`, which is consistent with the value return by the CLI's `sizeof` opcode (ECMA-335 Partition I, §8.9.1). Since nullable types are treated as reference types, the C# [`sizeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx) operator cannot be used for this, even in an unsafe context. Instead, we use `TypedReference` and a 2-element array to calculate the same information.

```
public static int SizeOf<T>()
{
    T[] array = new T[2];
    TypedReference elem1 = __makeref(array[0]);
    TypedReference elem2 = __makeref(array[1]);

    unsafe
    {
        byte* address1 = (byte*)*(IntPtr*)(&elem1);
        byte* address2 = (byte*)*(IntPtr*)(&elem2);
        return (int)(address2 - address1);
    }
}
```

You can then use the following.

```
// This returns 8 on my test, but the runtime is free to change this to
// any value greater than sizeof(int)+sizeof(bool)
int nullableSize = sizeof(int?);
```

Comment: Absolutely wrong answer please don't misguide the above code won't be compiled

Comment: Of course it compiles.  You need to tick the Allow Unsafe Code in the Build options on the project.