# Storage requirements of primitive types in Win x64

Tags: c#, .net, 64-bit, memory-management, primitive-types

For either `List` with `n` elements, which (if any) requires more storage on x64 machine:

```
List<int>
```

-or-

```
List<long>
```

I guess the question can be rephrased as:

On x64, does an `int` take any less space than a `long`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`int` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w.aspx) is an alias for the [`System.Int32` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx) which is always 32 bits wide, regardless of platform. Likewise, the [`long` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx) is an alias for the [`System.Int64` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.aspx) which is always 64 bits wide, regardless of platform.

Answer (score 0):

See [sizeof(int) on x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651956/sizeofint-on-x64)

On any architecture, `int` is 32-bits and `long` is 64-bits

Answer (score 0):

`List<long>` will require 4 more bytes of memory per item. It doesn't matter if you're running on a 32 bit or a 64 bit OS, or if your .NET application targets 32 bit versus 64 bit.