# int behavior at 32/64 bit process?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, int

I'm a process of 64 bit, my `int` size is 8 bytes.

I'm referencing a dll which is compiled to 32 bit.

This dll has a function which accepts an `int` parameter.

What will happen?

I'm sending a `8 byte` to a `4 byte` "container" ?

Comment: Take a look at [this][1] post. I think this should help u.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651956/sizeofint-on-x64

Comment: IntPtr changes size on the relevant platform, but int doesn't. Due to the very minimal direct pointer use in C#, platform changes are usually transparent in fully managed apps.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth so in 64 bit process  , int will have the same max value but will "accessed" as 8 byte container ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir no; you will still be sending 4 bytes to a 4 byte container. At least at the .NET/C# level. What happens *underneath* that (in terms of the CPU registers etc) is an implementation detail.

Comment: @RoyiNamir No, I was referring to the `IntPtr` type, which actually does change size (according to its Size property) depending on what CLI is used. As Marc stated in his answer, pointers and references become larger (as they obviously have to accommodate 64-bit address space).

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth sorry to my misunderstanding , but if im a 64 bit process and im referencing an int ( which i know has max value which can be held in 4 byte) - why my pointer need to be at size of 8 ? i *know* that the int value im referencing can be held at 4 byte , so why  im enlarging my reference size ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Refer to Marc's comment above, it'll still be 4 bytes. The CLI is responsible for managing the memory of that type when you use it in methods.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "referencing a dll which is compiled to 32 bit"? Is this DLL a managed assembly with the platform target set to "x86", or is it a native DLL compiled for x86? The two behave quite differently. If, for example, you have managed EXE with platform set to "x64" and it references a managed DLL with platform set to "x86", the latter's platform will be *ignored* and it will be JIT compiled as x64.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, in 64-bit / C#, an `int` is still 4 bytes.

In C#, `int` is **always** merely an alias to `global::System.Int32`

What will change is the *reference* size and *pointer* size, but that is all abstracted by the IL anyway - nothing needs to change. Note, though, that the CLI is only going to be 32 bit **xor** (nand?) 64 bit. You might need one of them to be "Any CPU".

Comment: Hi Marc, can you elaborate on that CLI comment please?

Comment: The actual process that spawns at runtime is going to have a fixed 32/64 mode. It can't be both. There are separate CLIs for x86 and x64. The relevant CLI will load, but: if one dll is **strictly** x86, and another is **strictly** x64, they may not work well together. "Any CPU" would be far more friendly.

Comment: so where is the size of 8 byte enteres here ? (intptr)

Comment: @Royi it doesn't. Nothing relating to `int` will be 8 bytes. When I mention 32/64 above, I'm talking about the process.

Comment: @MarcGravell so why sizeof intptr is 8 (64bit proc)? this is the part which i dont understand....:(

Comment: The *pointer* size can vary based on the system, but not the size of the INT *value*  it points out.

Comment: @Marc Oh I see, yes I was aware of that. I was curious if your statement was trying to say something else. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Tigran so i guess i dont know what is _pointer size_ meaning.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: pointer is a *data type* by itself that contains *address* to another space, where value is. So the size of the *pointer* depends on the system, but the size of the *field* where the value is, in **this** case remains 4bytes.

Comment: @Tigran isnt it a waste ? my reference  is a"8 byte" magnitude , but the max value which can held in this region can be stored only as "4 byte"  ?

Comment: @Royi: it is, but how you gonna manage OS in a way it deals with different pointer sizes, especially in mixed processes, where you can have *only* 64bit data mixed with *only* 32bit data. It becomes mess to manage, if not impossible. Forget about CLR, think about OS design, cause the pointer size is defined by OS and not by CLR.

Comment: @Tigran now you made me understand . thanks. ( that was the missing part ) .....:)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: what do you mean ?

Comment: @Tigran i mean  : if in 64 bit env  , the pointer size to int is 8 byte.....what will be the size of pointer to a short param ?

Comment: I will be 8, by the way, it is a pointer type, so on 64bit, it is 8.

Answer (score 3):

It always maps to `System.Int32` hence would be needing only 4

Answer (score 3):

In c# ints are the same size in 32bit and 64bit assemblies. `int` or `Int32` is always 32bit while `long` or `Int64` is always 64bit.

Comment: so in 64 bit process , int will have the same max value but will "accessed" as 8 byte container ?

Answer (score 1):

`int` is always 32 bit (4 bytes) in C#, but not in some other languages like C++.
`System.IntPtr` is 4 bytes on an x86 machine and 8 bytes on a 64 bit OS. Use this if you want OS dependend integer types.