# Difference between variable size and variable range

Tags: c#, .net, functional-programming

Is it correct to assume that if for instance I would write

```
sizeof(int)
```

then it would return the number of bytes a variable can support

and on the other hand the ranges are the integral range value of the variable can be assigned to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sizeof(int) on x64?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651956/sizeofint-on-x64)

Answer (score 1):

That sounds about right - the `sizeof` operator returns the number of bytes it would take to hold a value of the given data type.

Instead of trying to derive the integral range from the result, you should use the `MaxValue` and `MinValue` properties of that integral data type like this:

```
int.MaxValue
int.MinValue
```